# Connect To MySQL Server Asynchronously

Tags: php, mysql, asynchronous

I am writing a custom PHP MySQL library which will connect to multiple MySQL servers, and provide application level load balancing. Basically it tries to connect to an array of servers (all of them), the first to successfully connect wins.

The problem, is that for the life of me, I don't see a way with either the `mysql` or `mysqli` PHP libraries to say connect asynchronously, i.e. with a callback. Obviously I don't want to block  for each connection attempt, or the library will have to wait for the timeout, then try the next server.

It should work something like:

```
foreach($servers as $server) {
    mysql_async_connect($server, function($connection) {
        if($connection) {
            //Use this connection, successful
        }
    }
}
```

How is this possible? Has anybody written an asynchronous PHP library to connect to MySQL? Thanks.

Comment: That's why we [don't use PHP](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/rdbms.html) for this.

Comment: Yeah, I know I could write this in node, but the application code is PHP. :) May have to result to using a legit load balancer.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do won't work - PHP is only pseudo-multithreaded.

This means that if multiple users access the same script, both requests are executed parallel if it runs on a multithreaded machine. But you can't specify seperate threads which are started from a single script call.

What you could do is to create an AJAX-Application with javascript which uses callbacks, using php on the server side to fetch your data.